# ECSlidingViewContoller view not rotating

Tags: ios, objective-c, ecslidingviewcontroller

For some reason, if I subclass ECSlidingViewContoller, it won't rotate (and neither will any subview).

Basically if I do this, `popUpViewController.view` won't rotate:

```
@interface DSlidingViewController : ECSlidingViewController
```

---

```
DPopUpViewController *popUpViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:identifier];
[self addChildViewController:popUpViewController];
[self.view addSubview:popUpViewController.view];
[popUpViewController.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

NSDictionary *viewDictionary = @{@"view": popUpViewController.view};

NSArray *verticalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[view]|"
                                                                       options:0
                                                                       metrics:nil
                                                                         views:viewDictionary];
NSArray *horizontalConstraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[view]|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:viewDictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:verticalConstraints];
[self.view addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
```

But if I change the interface to this, everything works as expected. `popUpViewController.view` will rotate and occupy the whole screen. (But obviously this is no good since I need ECSliding).

```
@interface DSlidingViewController : UIViewController
```

So I have two questions:

1. Is it possible to make this work? If so, what am I doing wrong?
2. If it's not possible, then where should I add `popUpViewController.view` to to make it behave like a `UIAlertView`? (It must be shown above ECSliding's leftMenu and topView).

Answer (score 0):

You should either forward `UIViewController`'s methods:

```
– willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:
– didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:
```

from your `self` controller to your sliding controller, or better implement controller containment through:

```
addChildViewController:
removeFromParentViewController
willMoveToParentViewController:
didMoveToParentViewController:
```

That would go like this:

```
self.popUpViewController = ...
[self addChildViewController: self.popUpViewController];
[self.view addSubview: self.popUpViewController.view];
```

For the latter approach, have a look at "Implementing a Container View Controller" section in [UIViewController reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Self IS the sliding view controller.